# info.magnolia.objectfactory.MgnlInstantiationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: magnolia

I am Running a project of Magnolia-cms technology using Magnolia-blossom. While starting the project  I am getting this following Error :

> ERROR info.magnolia.cms.beans.config.ConfigLoader :
>
> An unspecified error occurred during initialization: 
>         java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 
>         info.magnolia.objectfactory.MgnlInstantiationException: 
>                     java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

This is the full Stack Trace

> 2015-03-23 08:47:02,072 INFO  info.magnolia.context.LifeTimeJCRSessionUtil      : Will handle lifetime sessions because the system context is of type interface info.magnolia.context.ThreadDependentSystemContext
>   2015-03-23 08:47:02,601 ERROR info.magnolia.cms.beans.config.ConfigLoader       : An unspecified error occurred during initialization: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>        info.magnolia.objectfactory.MgnlInstantiationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at info.magnolia.objectfactory.ObjectManufacturer.newInstance(ObjectManufacturer.java:115)
>       at info.magnolia.objectfactory.ObjectManufacturer.newInstance(ObjectManufacturer.java:102)
>       at info.magnolia.objectfactory.guice.GuiceComponentProvider.newInstanceWithParameterResolvers(GuiceComponentProvider.java:121)
>       at info.magnolia.objectfactory.guice.GuiceComponentProvider.newInstance(GuiceComponentProvider.java:107)
>       at info.magnolia.objectfactory.Components.newInstance(Components.java:89)
>       at info.magnolia.module.ModuleManagerImpl.newVersionHandler(ModuleManagerImpl.java:222)
>       at info.magnolia.module.ModuleManagerImpl.checkForInstallOrUpdates(ModuleManagerImpl.java:176)
>       at info.magnolia.cms.beans.config.ConfigLoader.load(ConfigLoader.java:148)
>       at info.magnolia.init.MagnoliaServletContextListener$1.doExec(MagnoliaServletContextListener.java:248)
>       at info.magnolia.context.MgnlContext$VoidOp.exec(MgnlContext.java:414)
>       at info.magnolia.context.MgnlContext$VoidOp.exec(MgnlContext.java:411)
>       at info.magnolia.context.MgnlContext.doInSystemContext(MgnlContext.java:385)
>       at info.magnolia.init.MagnoliaServletContextListener.startServer(MagnoliaServletContextListener.java:245)
>       at info.magnolia.init.MagnoliaServletContextListener.contextInitialized(MagnoliaServletContextListener.java:171)
>       at info.magnolia.init.MagnoliaServletContextListener.contextInitialized(MagnoliaServletContextListener.java:125)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5524)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>       at info.magnolia.objectfactory.ObjectManufacturer.newInstance(ObjectManufacturer.java:109)
>       ... 23 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: info/magnolia/module/form/setup/ChangeValidationToMultiValuedPropertyTask
>       at info.magnolia.module.templatingkit.setup.STKModuleVersionHandler.(STKModuleVersionHandler.java:364)
>       ... 28 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: info.magnolia.module.form.setup.ChangeValidationToMultiValuedPropertyTask
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
>       ... 29 more
>   2015-03-23 08:47:02,661 WARN  magnolia.jcr.node2bean.impl.Node2BeanProcessorImpl: Can't instantiate bean for /server/filters/deviceDetection
>   info.magnolia.jcr.node2bean.Node2BeanException: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:
>
> 2015-03-23 08:47:02,661 WARN  magnolia.jcr.node2bean.impl.Node2BeanProcessorImpl: Can't instantiate bean for /server/filters/deviceDetection
>   info.magnolia.jcr.node2bean.Node2BeanException: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:

1) Module instance for module [device-detection] not available, most likely because the module has not yet been started. Inject a Provider<> instead to get access to the module instance when it's available.
  at info.magnolia.objectfactory.guice.GuiceComponentConfigurationModule.bindProvider(GuiceComponentConfigurationModule.java:161)
  while locating info.magnolia.module.devicedetection.DeviceDetectionModule

> 1 error
>       at info.magnolia.jcr.node2bean.impl.Node2BeanTransformerImpl.newBeanInstance(Node2BeanTransformerImpl.java:261)
>       at info.magnolia.jcr.node2bean.impl.Node2BeanProcessorImpl.toBean(Node2BeanProcessorImpl.java:135)
>       at info.magnolia.jcr.node2bean.impl.Node2BeanProcessorImpl.toMap(Node2BeanProcessorImpl.java:227)
>       at info.magnolia.jcr.node2bean.impl.Node2BeanProcessorImpl.toBean(Node2BeanProcessorImpl.java:132)
>       at info.magnolia.jcr.node2bean.impl.Node2BeanProcessorImpl.toBean(Node2BeanProcessorImpl.java:94)
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.FilterManagerImpl.createConfiguredFilters(FilterManagerImpl.java:188)
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.FilterManagerImpl.createRootFilter(FilterManagerImpl.java:166)
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.FilterManagerImpl$2.doExec(FilterManagerImpl.java:107)
>       at info.magnolia.context.MgnlContext$VoidOp.exec(MgnlContext.java:414)
>       at info.magnolia.context.MgnlContext$VoidOp.exec(MgnlContext.java:411)
>       at info.magnolia.context.MgnlContext.doInSystemContext(MgnlContext.java:385)
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.FilterManagerImpl.init(FilterManagerImpl.java:103)
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlMainFilter.init(MgnlMainFilter.java:81)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4854)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5542)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:

Why I am getting this error?

Can any one please help me with this to resolve.

Comment: Can you share the entire stack trace? There's not enough information in that to say what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: info.magnolia.module.form.setup.ChangeValidationToMultiValuedPropertyTask

Looks like you are missing the form module.